# How to stop using DLL and statically link to a LIB?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, static-libraries

I have a VB 20008 Express project which currently uses a DLL. I would rather distribute a single .EXE

I used DLL2lib and converted it to a library, but as I haven't done this before,

1. How can remove the DLL from my project? The Project menu has an "Add resource" option, but I can't find any way to remove it (it doesn't show up in Project/Properties).  Do I simply remove the Imports statements from my code?
2. How do I statically link to the library?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For .NET assemblies, use [ILMerge](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=22914587-b4ad-4eae-87cf-b14ae6a939b0&displaylang=en)

And for removing a reference, simply select it and press delete (or right-click and press remove)